# QgsTask in PyQGIS Standalone Application

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, tasks

I'm playing around with the task examples from the QGIS documentation: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html

Besides the typo at the bottom (dosomething instead of doSomething) I haven't changed the code. But no matter which of the methods I use, I always get this error in the console:

> QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting

This only happens in my standalone application. In the python console inside of QGIS it works. What's my mistake? I'm working with QGIS 3.4

Comment: Might be important: I also do some imports in my script, to make PyQGIS run:

`from qgis.core import *


qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.4", True)
qgs.initQgis()
`